# Add Form In Every Row with table helper Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi i am creating table using table helper, but in every row i want to add form, in html like this :

```
<table>
  <form action="">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="name2"></td>
  </tr>
  </form>

  <form action="">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="name2"></td>
  </tr>
  </form>
</table>
```

But i want in table helper:
 I have tried this one:

```
    $this->table->add_row(
                form_open('myAction').
                form_input('name'.$i),
                form_submit('Submit')
                form_close()
        );
```

And I use firebugs to inspect element produces, like this:

```
   <table>
     <tr>
       <form action="myAction">
         <td><input type="text" name="name1"></td>
       </form>
          <td><input type="submit"></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
```

why tag  doesn't show at the last tag , but show at the first tag .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some dots

```
$this->table->add_row(
            form_open('myAction').
            form_input('name'.$i).
            form_submit('Submit').
            form_close()
    );
```